# Unable to update InformationRightsManagementSettings using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, irm

The following request returns **Status 204**, indicating it was a success but the informationrights settings hasn't become updated when I take a look the IRM-settings in the web gui for the list.

The property `IrmEnabled` seems to have been updated on the list but not the **informationRightsManagementSettings**!?

```
var resp = await MakeJsonRequestAsync(new
{
    __metadata = new Metadata() { type = "SP.List" },
    IrmEnabled = true,
    IrmReject = true,
    IrmExpire = true,
    InformationRightsManagementSettings = new
    {
        __metadata = new Metadata() { type = "SP.InformationRightsManagementSettings" },
        AllowPrint = true,
        AllowScript = false,
        AllowWriteCopy = false,
        DisableDocumentBrowserView = false,
        DocumentAccessExpireDays = 90,
        DocumentLibraryProtectionExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6),
        EnableDocumentAccessExpire = false,
        EnableDocumentBrowserPublishingView = false,
        EnableGroupProtection = false,
        EnableLicenseCacheExpire = false,
        GroupName = "",
        LicenseCacheExpireDays = 31,
        PolicyDescription = "blaha",
        PolicyTitle = "blahej"
    }
},
"/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listId.ToString() + "')/",
newSiteUrl, 
accessToken, 
HttpMethod.Post, 
new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"X-Http-Method", "MERGE"},
    { "If-Match", "*" }
});
```

I have also tried to make a POST directly to `/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listId + "')/informationRightsManagementSettings` but it ends up in **Status 400** no matter what I do.

*Any help is greatly appreciated!*

Comment: Do you want to do this using REST only? you can also do it using CSOM

Comment: Yes, REST only please. @GaneshSanap

Comment: I am not able to find any concrete solution using REST :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure information right management by CSOM in SharePoint online. But I am not able to find any concrete solution to do it using REST API. For more detailed information, check things below links:

**References**:

1. [Office 365 – Automating the Configuration of Information Rights Management (IRM) using CSOM](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2015/09/07/office-365-automating-the-configuration-of-information-rights-management-irm-using-csom/)
2. [Sharepoint Online -O365- templates](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/projectserver/en-US/d506e8a1-da38-415c-a7df-3b5797201ac4/sharepoint-online-o365-templates?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

Check if the endpoint URI structure for InformationRightsManagementSettings object is correct according to the article below:

[SP.InformationRightsManagementSettings object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247077.aspx)

Also, I found that some developers are also getting the same error:

> The type SP.InformationRightsManagementSettings does not support HTTP POST method.

**Reference**:

1. [Cannot Update/Create IRM (Infromation Rights Management) on library/file using REST Api](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f496f464-f151-4180-9253-df274879038b/cannot-updatecreate-irm-infromation-rights-management-on-libraryfile-using-rest-api?forum=sharepointcustomization).

Comment: Okey, then I have a side-question. Is it possible to use CSOM with netstandard 2.0? We're doing this in a Azure Function

Comment: Not sure about netstandard 2.0 But you can use SharePoint CSOM with azure fucntions. Check [this](https://medium.com/ng-sp/serverless-azure-function-and-sharepoint-csom-7c176b63cfc9).